# NETWORK SERVICE user and joomla, file/folders not writable, Windows 2008 IIS7

Tags: iis-7, joomla, file-permissions

I'm trying to give the correct permissions to the user that Joomla (v1.6) runs as to enable uploading on a windows 2008 IIS7 box.  I'm finding lots of conflicting responses on ye-ole internets.

When I go to the System Information -> Directory Permissions page in Joomla admin I can see that all directories are not writable.  And, I've attempted the following.

I checked to make sure that -
My www service runs as: NETWORK SERVICE
My php-cgi.exe runs as: NETWORK SERVICE

I added the NETWORK SERVICE user to the root of the site (as a simple test) with full control and then went to advanced and had it propagate all permissions to sub-directories.  None of the folders became writable from Joomla's point of view.

The only way to get the folders (and there are many) writable by Joomla, so far, has been to give the everyone user write access.

This is completely baffling me.  I would really appreciate any help anyone can give!

Comment: There are two right settings. Application pool settings, where you have a default user (normally NETWORK SERVICE) and your web. NTFS rights are normally related to the user you setup with the web application. Check your properties of the web site, normally you have there an IUSR anomynous user. For testing (not for production) you can simple reset the NTFS permissions to "everyone" -> full access

Comment: If I give the everyone group write permission, it works.  If I give the NETWORK SERVICE user write permission, it does not.  Is there a user that I don't know about that I should be giving permissions to?

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, you have to setup proper rights for access.
The NETWORK SERVICE is the user for your application pool.
You can setup a user entity that access your local files.

As you can see in the screenshot (sorry, german only) you can choose your site, then check default settings and edit "connect as" and choose a user (you create a yoomla user before and grant rights to your local directories).

[image]

With this you can make it run imho.